# How do I italicize the word et al in apacite package

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, apacite

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{refere.bib}
    @article{k2016occurrence,
        author =        {K'oreje, KO and Vergeynst, Leendert and Ombaka, D and
            De Wispelaere, Patrick and Okoth, Maurice and
            Van Langenhove, Herman and Demeestere, Kristof},
        journal =       {Chemosphere},
        pages =         {238--244},
        publisher =     {Elsevier},
        title =         {Occurrence patterns of pharmaceutical residues in
            wastewater, surface water and groundwater of Nairobi
            and Kisumu city, Kenya},
        volume =        {149},
        year =          {2016},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[natbibapa,apaciteclassic]{apacite}

\author{author}
\title{title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
The corrections have been done as per the following chapters
\section{Preamble Pages}
\cite{k2016occurrence}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{refere.bib}
\end{document}
```

The LaTeX code runs but I want in the printed version the word et al to be italicized. I don't know how I can do this while still maintaining the use of package apacite. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apacite` uses macros to localise strings like "et al.", so you just have to redefine the relevant macros. This needs to happen in `\AtBeginDocument` after `apacite` has done its language selection.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa,apaciteclassic]{apacite}

\AtBeginDocument[apacite-localisation]{%
  \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{\emph{et al.}\hbox{}}%
  \renewcommand{\BOthersPeriod}[1]{\emph{et al.}\hbox{}}%
}
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{apacite-localisation}{after}{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{k2016occurrence,
  author    = {K'oreje, KO and Vergeynst, Leendert and Ombaka, D
               and De Wispelaere, Patrick and Okoth, Maurice
               and Van Langenhove, Herman and Demeestere, Kristof},
  journal   = {Chemosphere},
  pages     = {238--244},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  title     = {Occurrence Patterns of Pharmaceutical Residues in
               Wastewater, Surface Water and Groundwater of {Nairobi}
               and {Kisumu City}, {Kenya}},
  volume    = {149},
  year      = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{k2016occurrence}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: K’oreje et al. (2016)]

---

If you are using a LaTeX version with the new hook management system (2020-10-01 or above), you may want to use a labelled `\AtBeginDocument` hook with a rule to ensure proper execution order

```
\usepackage[natbibapa,apaciteclassic]{apacite}

\AtBeginDocument[apacite-localisation]{%
  \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{\emph{et al.}\hbox{}}%
  \renewcommand{\BOthersPeriod}[1]{\emph{et al.}\hbox{}}%
}
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{apacite-localisation}{after}{apacite}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved my problem